Pycharm static analysis doesn't infer subclass types as I wished
In the following python code, the TruckDriver class inherits from the Driver class, and the Truck class inherits from the Vehicle class.
The driver attribute of the Truck class is of TruckDriver type (which is specified in the type hint), and is passed to the constructor of the Vehicle class (which accepts the general Driver type).
However, Pycharm warns me in the Truck class about the driver not having TruckDriver-specific attributes. Specifically, it underlines the company attribute in the print(f"Company: {self.driver.company}") line, with the following warning :

Unresolved attribute reference 'company' for class 'Driver'

Is there a way I can resolve such warnings? I also use Ruff as a linter in my project but it doesn't seem to help here.
class Driver:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

class TruckDriver(Driver):
    def __init__(self, name: str, company: str):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.company = company

class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, driver: Driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def drive(self):
        print(f"{self.driver.name} is driving.")

class Truck(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, driver: TruckDriver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def drive(self):
        super().drive()
        print(f"Company: {self.driver.company}")


Use a generic vehicle:
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

D = TypeVar("D", bound="Driver")

class Driver:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

class TruckDriver(Driver):
    def __init__(self, name: str, company: str):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.company = company

class Vehicle(Generic[D]):
    def __init__(self, driver: D):
        self.driver = driver

    def drive(self):
        print(f"{self.driver.name} is driving.")

class Truck(Vehicle[TruckDriver]):
    def __init__(self, driver: TruckDriver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def drive(self):
        super().drive()
        print(f"Company: {self.driver.company}")

alice = Driver("Alice")
carol = TruckDriver("Carol", "Acme Truck Co.")

car = Vehicle(alice)
truck = Truck(carol)

car.drive()
truck.drive()


Indeed, I didn't know about Generics but it is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

@Gautzilla Note: Truck.__init__ is unnecessary and can be removed as it does nothing other than calling __init__ of the super class (which is the default behaviour) and the use of generics handles the type-checking on the super-class.
